# Jquery multiselect to slow for 1300 records

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I implemented this solution to get a MultiSelect DropDownList Box:
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#filter

However, it is to slow. Why do I need this? The user has to be able to select multiple medications. The total medication are 1300.

Should I have them filter the search box before populating it? Or is there a way I can improve the speed?

I am using MVC3 jquery

Comment: Which particular part is slow? The time taken to render the multi-select? 1300 options is a lot. Perhaps you need a better strategy - force the user to filter that list by typing in part of the name, and only pulling back entries that match what they typed, autocomplete style. Or just do autocomplete full stop, if they only need to pick one drug.

Comment: I would also suggest paginating the medications by name (first letter or something) and then including a search feature as well.

Comment: Definitely look into jQuery UI autocomplete instead, and filter the results server side before displaying them all to the end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My god i just found this http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ amazing!